# enabling TTL on an entire index

Tags: elasticsearch

Question is pretty straight forward, is there a way to enable TTL on the index level. effectively means all types created under this index will inherit an enabled TTL.
on the documentation it is said that "You can provide a per index/type default _ttl value as follows", but I wasn't able to request TTL on an index level.

in case it isn't possible, what workaround can be suggested ? in our environment new types are created all the time, and the data has to be removed after it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Please check out 'curator', which typically is a much better solution for enforcing retention policies than TTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using *default* option under mapping. Under an index , if you put any configuration under_default_ it would be applied to all the mappings whose these configurations  not defined under the same index.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index" -d'{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_ttl": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}'
```